# When are pickling methods of Dask collections used

Tags: dask

Dask collections supply methods for pickling like [`DataFrame`s](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/27d52b02bdd4c8e933f98698291fed51cf8d8642/dask/dataframe/core.py#L354-L358) and [`Array`s](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/27d52b02bdd4c8e933f98698291fed51cf8d8642/dask/array/core.py#L1063-L1064). Though IIUC collections themselves are not transmitted to workers. Instead the graph is extracted, optimized, and turned into tasks, which are then on workers (serializing data dependencies like Pandas and NumPy arrays). So in what cases are these pickling methods of Dask collections actually used?

Answer (score 0):

Pickling, or more generally serialization, is used primarily during communication.  Whenever data is passed between workers or from the client to the workers, the data must be converted to a sequence of bytes which can be moved across the wire and reconstituted without any loss of data.

For DataFrames, Dask uses pickle, and indeed, most things use pickle

```py
In [4]: from distributed.protocol import serialize

In [5]: serialize(pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2]}))
Out[5]:
({'serializer': 'pickle'},
 [b"\x80\x04\x95\xbc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x11pandas.core.frame\x94\x8c\tDataFrame\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x05_data\x94\x8c\x1epandas.core.internals.managers\x94\x8c\x0cBlockManager\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94(]\x94(\x8c\x18pandas.core.indexes.base\x94\x8c\n_new_Index\x94\x93\x94h\x0b\x8c\x05Index\x94\x93\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04data\x94\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x0c_reconstruct\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94K\x00\x85\x94C\x01b\x94\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01\x85\x94h\x15\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02O8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01|\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?t\x94b\x89]\x94\x8c\x01a\x94at\x94b\x8c\x04name\x94Nu\x86\x94R\x94h\r\x8c\x19pandas.core.indexes.range\x94\x8c\nRangeIndex\x94\x93\x94}\x94(h'N\x8c\x05start\x94K\x00\x8c\x04stop\x94K\x03\x8c\x04step\x94K\x01u\x86\x94R\x94e]\x94h\x14h\x17K\x00\x85\x94h\x19\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01K\x03\x86\x94h\x1e\x8c\x02i8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94b\x89C\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x94t\x94ba]\x94h\rh\x0f}\x94(h\x11h\x14h\x17K\x00\x85\x94h\x19\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01\x85\x94h!\x89]\x94h%at\x94bh'Nu\x86\x94R\x94a}\x94\x8c\x060.14.1\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04axes\x94h\n\x8c\x06blocks\x94]\x94}\x94(\x8c\x06values\x94h6\x8c\x08mgr_locs\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x05slice\x94\x93\x94K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87\x94R\x94uaust\x94b\x8c\x04_typ\x94\x8c\tdataframe\x94\x8c\t_metadata\x94]\x94\x8c\x05attrs\x94}\x94ub."])
```

For NumPy, Dask will use pickle but also needs more information to make things fast and reduce copies.  Luckily, Dask can [customize serializers](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/protocol/numpy.py) for specific data types

```
In [8]: serialize(np.arange(5))
Out[8]:
({'dtype': (0, '<i8'),
  'shape': (5,),
  'strides': (8,),
  'lengths': [40],
  'type': 'numpy.ndarray',
  'type-serialized': b'\x80\x04\x95\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94.',
  'serializer': 'dask'},
 [<memory at 0x118d942c0>])
```

I'd recommend reading through https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/serialization.html for Dask specifics on serialization or look through https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/protocol/ for code details on how serialization is implemented

Comment: This is certainly true of Pandas DataFrames and NumPy arrays used within Dask collections. Though that's not really what is being asked here. Instead this is asking, when does a Dask DataFrame or Dask Array get pickled?

Comment: Ah, apologies for missing reading the question.  As best as I can tell pickle is used in Array during map_block callas with `block_info` See the [block Info](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/27d52b02bdd4c8e933f98698291fed51cf8d8642/dask/array/tests/test_array_core.py#L1193-L1212) .  I don't think dask uses pickle for dask dataframes but other libraries might. 

Should I delete my answer to the question above ?